# require() not working with interpolated string when fetching an image in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using an Image component as a background in React Native and am currently providing the source prop with an image as follows, which works.

```
const ImageWrapper = (props) => {
      return (
        <Image source={require('../../../images/testingImages/cells.png')} style={styles.imageView}>
          {props.children}
        </Image>
      );
    };
```

However, I would like to provide the require with an interpolated string with the name of an image provided by a prop as so:

```
require(`../../../images/testingImages/${props.imgURL}`)
```

But whenever I do so (even when I create the string as a seperate variable without using ES6 and pass it into require). I get the error -

> "unknown named module '../../../images/testingImages/cells.png'".

Is there away to get the image without using require? As I would love to be able to pass the image url as a prop so that I can reuse the component when I want to change the background.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully somebody else can provide a solution to your exact problem because I was having the same issue, but my workaround was to pass the entire value for `source` as a prop. I had that as a value to a certain key for each map within a list in my scenario, so that was clean enough for me. But that may be just moving the problem up a level in your case.

Comment: thanks for your help! By the entire value for source what do you mean the value that require() returns? If so how do I find this, I have been googling but can't work out what require() is actually returning!

Comment: @LuckyLukas So I have a class called `Icon` in my `Tabs` class. `Tabs.render()` has `<Icon image={this.props.route.icon}/>` as part of its markup. The `route` here is a map where the value for the `icon` key is my full image value (e.g., `require('../images/icons/keyboard.png')`. I don't know what it's actually returning either, but it works and it's clean enough for my purposes, so I just left it like that.

Answer (score 2):

First create a file with image required - React native images must be loaded this way.

assets/index.js

```
export const leftChevron = require('./left-chevron.png'); 
export const rightChevron = require('./right-chevron.png'); 
export const circle = require('./oval-bottom-right.png'); 
export const homeandgarden = require('./homeAndGarden.png');
```

Now import all your assets

App.js

```
import * as All  from '../../assets';
```

You can now use your image as an interpolated value where imageValue is the same as named local file:

```
<Image style={styles.image} source={All[`${imageValue}`]}></Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it solves your issue but if your image is available over network you can use your base URL to create a URL to the image and use that URL directly inside  as a source.

```
var fileName = "trolltunga.jpg";
var imagesBaseUrl = "https://www.w3schools.com/css/";
var image = imagesBaseUrl+fileName;
const imageURL = {url:image}

class App extends React.Component {
render() {
 return (
  <Image source={imageURL} style={styles.imageView}>
 </Image>
  );
 }
}
```

For demo check here https://rnplay.org/apps/hEYzcA

Comment: Images will be local but I shall bear in mind as will no doubt encounter the same problem in future when images are available over  network. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got round it specifically, not really a perfect answer but works fro my purpose. I think the require is called when the component loads and hence the string doesn't get a chance to interpolate to be passed. So instead I import the relevant image in the parent component of image wrapper:

```
import jungle from '../../images/jungle.jpg';
```

Then pass as a prop to Image Wrapper

```
<ImageWrapper image={jungle} />
```

Then pass this prop to the image source component:

```
<Image source={this.props.image} style={styles.imageView}>
          { this.props.children }
</Image>
```